# Auth0: How to update user_metadata from rules?

Tags: authentication, oauth, auth0

It is possible to update user_metadata from rules?
I know. it an be done through rest calls passing access token shown [here](https://auth0.com/docs/users/update-metadata-with-the-management-api), but is it possible to do it through the rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `address` property needs to be added to user_metadata, then

```
const updateUsermetadata = (session) => {
    user.user_metadata = user.user_metadata || {};
    if (user.user_metadata.address !== null && user.user_metadata.address !== undefined) {} else {
      user.user_metadata.address = user.user_metadata.address || {};
      user.user_metadata.address = "123 blvd, NYC 11011";
    }

    // persist the user_metadata update
    auth0.users.updateUserMetadata(user.user_id, user.user_metadata)
      .then(function () {
        callback(null, user, context);
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        callback(err);
      });
 };
```